Finding eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of integral operator
I have the following problem: Let $A:C^\infty\rightarrow C^\infty$ with
$$(Af)(x)=\int_{0}^{1}|x-y|f(y) dy.$$
I need to find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of $A$.
To find the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions, we need to find $f(x)$ such that
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|x-y|f(y) dy=\lambda f(x)
$$
holds with $\lambda$ as the eigenvalues.
To do this I wrote
$$
\int_{0}^{1}|x-y|f(y) dy = \int_{0}^{x}(x-y)f(y) dy + \int_{x}^{1}(y-x)f(y) dy
$$
and differentiated two times. With the first derivative I've got
$$
\int_{0}^{x}f(y) dy - \int_{x}^{1}f(y) dy = \lambda f'(x)
$$
and then finally
$$
2f(x)=\lambda f''(x).
$$
The solution to this differential equation I've got is
$$
f(x)=Ae^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}}x}+Be^{-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}}x}.
$$
Now my problem is that I don't know how to derive $A$ and $B$ and then finally the eigenvalues. I tried to find initial conditions that I can work with, but was unsuccessful to do so. It should be mentioned that I already looked at this, but I didn't understand how he got the inital conditions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Edit: I took the second derivative of both sides and set $x=0$. This leads to (setting $k=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\lambda}}$)
$$-\int_{0}^{1}f(y)\text{d}y=\frac{2}{k^2} f'(0)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow -\frac{1}{k}\left(Ae^k-Be^{-k}+B-A\right)=\frac{2}{k}(A-B)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow B=Ae^k$$
This would simplify the function to
$$
f(x)=A\left(e^{kx}+e^{k(1-x)}\right)
$$
but again I'm stuck. I now know that $f(x)=f(1-x)$ but I don't know how that could help. I tried to do the same on the non-differentiated integral, but I get a term that is of no use. If someone has an idea, then please share.

I think you need to impose finiteness at infinity and that'll get rid of the left exponential, then it follows by summing over all the spectra and so the final solution will be the fourier transform of your new function. You should be given something else though...

don't call the operator and the coefficient by the same name

You could maybe give the Laplace transform a try too

have you verified that $f$ indeed obeys the integral equation?

I've tried an integral-calculator to verify it, but it couldn't do it. I will try it later by hand.

Similar question here
